# How can you apply dynamic connectivity problem to digital photos?

Tags: algorithms, digital-image-processing

I started learning DSA recently and I came across the [Dynamic Connectivity Problem](https://www.codingninjas.com/blog/2021/02/10/dynamic-connectivity-problem/). One of the listed real-world applications of the Dynamic Connectivity Problem is "pixels in digital photos."  How do you apply it to photos?  What is it used for?

I can understand its usage in a social network or a network of computers but what is its application in digital photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem manifests when maintaining connectivity data either in edges or objects within the image.  For machine vision you might want to increase the reliability of an edge detection algorithm by examining the image at multiple brightness and contrast levels and seeing whether previously edge correlations are reinforced or weakened.

For a series of related images, e.g. video, you might want to track pixel connectivity between images as an aid to compressing the video stream.  Compression is essentially the elimination of redundant encodings of data, and tracking which nearby pixels are similar is a necessary first step for some algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.